# JavaEE 7: CDI+OSGI - one real example

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, osgi, cdi

There are two great technologies OSGI and CDI and I'm newbie in both of them. I use glassfish 4 and when I started to use it I hoped that such great server would provide all I'd learned. Now I need to use both technologies.  So what I have in practice:

> Bundle1 - servlet as frontcontroller + jsp
>  Bundle2 - service
>   providing controllers, commands,[models]
>  Bundle3 - EJB.

I can inject EJB to servlet - that's ok. I can inject service to servlet - that's ok. But I can't do the most necessary thing - I can't inject EJB to my controllers/commands/models etc - here I have to do manual lookup of EJB, but I want to use CDI!

My thoughts: The problem is that I can't create these objects from bundle2 without new!!! Because entry point in osgi bundle is osgi service. Other bundles work with this bundle via its service. So, I must inject my objects to service - however this doesn't work. Here are two possible reasons:

1. I do something wrong
2. It's not supported by weld\fighterfish.

If someone sees my mistake in my thoughts please correct me. So the question - can I inject EJB in controllers/commands, provided by service of bundle 2 or it's impossible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use stateless session beans for the services in bundle 2. So you can easily inject the EJB.

Comment: Thank you. How do you think using stateless EJB as service in bundle 2 is the only way?

Comment: It is not the only way but the easiest way. If you start your services using CDI then injecting CDI resources is easy. If you start them using a bundle activator then the CDI annotations will not work.

Comment: Please, explain - "If you start your services using CDI then injecting CDI resources is easy." How can I start my service in order I could inject controller in it? I mean not using EJB as service in bundle2.

Comment: You can use the Activator of course but then you do not have the CDI annotations. Btw. You can inject other OSGi services using CDI.